# How to give sound for my bingo game

Tags: audio

How can I give sound for my bingo game's game call?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use a trumpet, but the best option depends how your bingo game is implemented.

Comment: If it's implemented in Java, I suggest using a gamelan instead of a trumpet. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_of_Java

Comment: I'm more of a c# guy but it could probably be ported easily enough.  Call it nGamelan.